# What is the earliest we know wire-strung instruments to have existed?

Tags: strings, history, instruments, string-instruments

What is the earliest we know wire-strung instruments to have existed? I was reading about gut strings, nylon strings, wire strings used on guitar, and wanted to know, but couldn't find the answer where I thought I might.

Comment: One thing is certain: wire strings existed before nylon did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Wikipedia: Piano wire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano_wire):

> The oldest record of wire being made for musical instruments is from Augsburg in 1351.

This is based on Alfred Dolge's book *Pianos and Their Makers: A Comprehensive History of the Development of the Piano from the Monochord to the Concert Grand Player Piano* (1911), in which he writes:

> Records tell us that iron wire for musical instruments was drawn from Augsburg as early as 1351. (page 123, [Google books](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Pianos_and_Their_Makers/tCc5AQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0))

Comment: Any mention elsewhere of first use on guitars, lutes, violins, etc?

Answer (score 1):

An early wire strung instrument that helped promote using metal strings on guitars was the X braced Martin guitar.  From Guitar .com "X-bracing was considered unsubtle by most guitar makers in Europe at the time, who favoured a fan bracing pattern, but Martin broadly stuck with it, and it would eventually prove a masterstroke. As the guitar became more popular as the 20th century dawned, so did the demand for more volume, which led to the introduction of metal strings instead of the traditional catgut."